# Custom Vector/Dynamic Array C++ issue

Tags: c++, vector, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying to make my own vector in C++ so I could understand more how it works !
This is the code:

```
#pragma once

template<typename T>
class Vector {
public:
    Vector() {
        // allocate 2 elements
        ReAlloc(2);
    }

    void pushBack(const T& value) {
        if (m_Size >= m_Capacity) {
            ReAlloc(m_Capacity / 2);
        }
        m_Data[m_Size++] = value;
    }

    const T& operator[](size_t index) const {
        /*
        if (index >= m_Size) {
            // assert
        }
        */
        return m_Data[index];
    }

    T& operator[](size_t index) {
        /*
        if (index >= m_Size) {
            // assert
        }
        */
        return m_Data[index];
    }

    const size_t Size() const { return m_Size; }
    size_t Size() { return m_Size; }
private:
    T* m_Data = nullptr;
    size_t m_Size = 0;
    size_t m_Capacity = 0;
private:
    void ReAlloc(size_t newCapacity) {
        // 1. allocate a new block of memory
        // 2. copy/move old elements into the new block
        // 3. delete the old one

        T* newBlock = new T[newCapacity];
        if (newCapacity < m_Size) {
            m_Size = newCapacity;
        }
        for (size_t i = 0; i < m_Size; i++) {
            newBlock[i] = m_Data[i];
        }
        delete[] m_Data;
        m_Data = newBlock;
        m_Capacity = newCapacity;
    }
};
```

However, When I try to use it from main.cpp like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "Vector.h"

#define print(x) std::cout << x
#define println(x) std::cout << x << std::endl

template<typename T>
void PrintVector(Vector<T>& vector) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vector.Size(); i++) {
        println(vector[i]);
    }
    println("------------------------------------------");
}

int main() {
    Vector<std::string> vector;
    vector.pushBack("Ahmed");
    vector.pushBack("C++");
    vector.pushBack("Vector");

    PrintVector(vector);
}
```

The code give me this output:

```
Ahmed
Vector
------------------------------------------
(process 7540) exited with code -1073740940.
```

it's not even printing C++ and the code acts weird, whenever I try o change anything the output became more mess, Could anyone tell me what did I do wrong please ?!.
Thx ! :)

Comment: Unrelated, the 2 functions `const size_t Size() const { return m_Size; }
    size_t Size() { return m_Size; }` are useless. Combine them to a single function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `pushBack` function, when the size is greater than or equal to capacity, you are doing:

```
ReAlloc(m_Capacity / 2);
```

which doesn't make sense. If you need additional space to add elements, you should *increase* the capacity of the underlying array, not decrease it by half.

You are probably looking for:

```
ReAlloc(m_Capacity * 2);
```

which doubles the underlying capacity.

Here's a working [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KsKer1), without any segfault.

Comment: actually I was trying to do something like this "ReAlloc(m_Size / 2);" but I did that accidentally "ReAlloc(m_Capacity / 2);" Thx I correct it now but the code still not working.
it prints nothing and gave me this exit code "(process 15228) exited with code -1073741819."

Comment: But the same issue arises with `ReAlloc(m_Size / 2);` Why are you allocating less memory when you need more?

Comment: Cuz if i did something like this "m_Size * 2" if the size was 2 It'll increase to 4, i want to increase it by the half so if the size was 4 i want to increase it to the half of 4 which is 2 so it became 6 instead of 8 as a try to save more memory :)

Comment: Then you want `ReAlloc(m_size + m_Size / 2);`

Comment: @AMZ That's very inefficient. The usual practise is to avoid expensive reallocations by doubling the memory allocated each time.

Comment: @cigien but if the size was 4 it'll increase it to 8 then divide it by 2 so it's 4 again !

Comment: Do you mean `int n = 4; int x = n + n / 2;` will give `x` the value `4`? Try it out and see what happens.

Comment: @john ik, but i'm this is just a test so i can understand how it really works and how could i modify it, i won't use it in real word :)

Comment: @cigien "*Then you want `ReAlloc(m_size + m_Size / 2);`*" - alternatively `ReAlloc(m_size * 1.5);`, though that won't work if `m_size` is 1 since `1.5` will get truncated to `1` so the array won't grow

Comment: @AMZ "*i totally forgot that the priority is always to dividing*" - then it is better to always be explicit about what you really want, eg: `ReAlloc(m_size + (m_Size / 2));` Note this fails if `m_Size` is 1, since `1 / 2` is 0 in integer math, so the array won't grow

Comment: @RemyLebeau ik, that's why i gave it size 2 as default :)

Comment: @AMZ Maybe, but a good vector also allows removing items. It might make more sense to round up the new capacity when growing. For instance, grow the capacity by simply adding X items at a time. Or, increase the current capacity by 1.5x..2x and then round that up to the next multiple of a given delta.